# How can i delete a user which has revoked consents assigned to him?

Tags: fusionauth

**Summary:** When trying to delete a user in FusionAuth which has a consent assigned to him (even revoking the consent doesn't change the behaviour), i get a foreign key constraint violation error from FusionAuth.

**FusionAuth Version:** 1.7.4 (running FusionAuth on Kubernetes)

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Create a user in FusionAuth
2. Register an application to the user in FusionAuth
3. Create a consent in FusionAuth
4. Assign the previously generated consent to the user in FusionAuth
5. Try to delete the user via the FusionAuth Web-UI or the API (event if the consent gets before revoked, the same result as stated below occurs)

**Actual Result:** Foreign key constraint violation (see stack trace below)

```
### SQL: DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "user_consents_fk_2" on table "user_consents"
  Detail: Key (id)=(f5d429b1-1c4a-4161-8d44-637b095992e9) is still referenced from table "user_consents".
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:200)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.delete(DefaultSqlSession.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionManager$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionManager.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionManager.delete(SqlSessionManager.java:256)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:68)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.delete(Unknown Source)
    at io.fusionauth.api.service.user.DefaultUserService._delete(DefaultUserService.java:1608)
    at io.fusionauth.api.service.user.DefaultUserService.delete(DefaultUserService.java:546)
    at org.mybatis.guice.transactional.TransactionalMethodInterceptor.invoke(TransactionalMethodInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.mybatis.guice.transactional.TransactionalMethodInterceptor.invoke(TransactionalMethodInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.mybatis.guice.transactional.TransactionalMethodInterceptor.invoke(TransactionalMethodInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.mybatis.guice.transactional.TransactionalMethodInterceptor.invoke(TransactionalMethodInterceptor.java:96)
    at io.fusionauth.app.action.api.UserAction.delete(UserAction.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor138.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:436)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.execute(DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.java:84)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.perform(DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.java:64)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.validation.DefaultValidationWorkflow.perform(DefaultValidationWorkflow.java:47)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.security.DefaultSecurityWorkflow.perform(DefaultSecurityWorkflow.java:81)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultPostParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultPostParameterWorkflow.java:50)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.content.DefaultContentWorkflow.perform(DefaultContentWorkflow.java:52)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultParameterWorkflow.java:57)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultURIParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultURIParameterWorkflow.java:102)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.scope.DefaultScopeRetrievalWorkflow.perform(DefaultScopeRetrievalWorkflow.java:58)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.message.DefaultMessageWorkflow.perform(DefaultMessageWorkflow.java:45)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionMappingWorkflow.perform(DefaultActionMappingWorkflow.java:126)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.StaticResourceWorkflow.perform(StaticResourceWorkflow.java:97)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.RequestBodyWorkflow.perform(RequestBodyWorkflow.java:89)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.security.DefaultSavedRequestWorkflow.perform(DefaultSavedRequestWorkflow.java:57)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.DefaultMVCWorkflow.perform(DefaultMVCWorkflow.java:91)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.DefaultWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(DefaultWorkflowChain.java:44)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.FilterWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(FilterWorkflowChain.java:50)
    at org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.PrimeFilter.doFilter(PrimeFilter.java:84)
    at com.inversoft.maintenance.servlet.MaintenanceModePrimeFilter.doFilter(MaintenanceModePrimeFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.inversoft.servlet.CORSFilter.handleNonCORS(CORSFilter.java:748)
    at com.inversoft.servlet.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.inversoft.servlet.UTF8Filter.doFilter(UTF8Filter.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "user_consents_fk_2" on table "user_consents"
  Detail: Key (id)=(f5d429b1-1c4a-4161-8d44-637b095992e9) is still referenced from table "user_consents".
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:157)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:74)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:198)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
```

**Expected Result:**
User is deleted from FusionAuth database

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please open a support ticket on the FusionAuth GitHub issue tracker here: https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues

Comment: Thanks Brian. Will open a bug in GitHub.